# how to select players join the game and start a game

Tags: java, object, constructor

I am a beginner in Java, and I've been creating a practicing project for a game. For this purpose, I've already put some features in this project, and I separate the entire project into three files: Nimsys, NimPlayer, NimGame.

I've created these features.

1. addplayer into playerList in the NimPlayer.
2. removeplayer
3. editplayer

Now, I want two of the players to join the game, and do the following:

4. Score record
5. The times the player has played.

What I did was trying to store the user data (addplayer) from the prompt input, and brought the game to be played (last part of the incomplete code).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Nimsys {

public static String[] splitName(String inName) {
    String[] splittedLine = inName.split(",");
    String[] name = null;
    if (splittedLine.length==3) {
        String userName = splittedLine[0].trim();
        String familyName = splittedLine[1].trim();
        String givenName = splittedLine[2].trim();
        name = new String[3];
        name[0] = userName;
        name[1] = familyName;
        name[2] = givenName;
    }
    return name;
}

public static String [] splitData(String dataIn) {
    String[] splittedLine = dataIn.split(",");
    String[] data = null;
    if (splittedLine.length==4) {
        String initialStone = splittedLine[0];
        String stoneRemoval = splittedLine[1];
        String player1 = splittedLine[2].trim();
        String player2 = splittedLine[3].trim();
        data = new String[4];
        data[0] = initialStone;
        data[1] = stoneRemoval;
        data[2] = player1;
        data[3] = player2;
    }
    return data;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.print('$');
        String commandin = in.next();

        if (commandin.equals("addplayer")) { 
            String inName = in.nextLine();
            String[] name = splitName(inName);

            //Make sure the vadality of in name
            if (name!=null && name.length==3) {
                for (int i = 0; i < NimPlayer.getId(); i ++) {
                    String userCheck = NimPlayer.getPlayer()[i].getUserName();
                    if (userCheck.contains(name[0])) {
                        System.out.println("The player already exist");//Test if player has been created
                    } 
            }
                NimPlayer.createPlayer(name[0], name[1], name[2]);
                System.out.println("The player has been created.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not Valid! Please enter again!");
            }          
        }

        if (commandin.equals("removeplayer")) {
            //cannot loop through the entire null array, would be NullPointerException
            String removeUserName = in.nextLine().trim();


            /*System.out.println("Are you sure you want to remove all players? (y/n) \n");
            //System.out.print('$');
            commandin = in.next();
                if (commandin.equals("y")) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < NimPlayer.getId(); i++) {
                        NimPlayer.getPlayer()[i] = null;
                        System.out.println("Remove all the players");
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.print('$');
                }*/
            //commandin = in.next();
            for (int i = 0; i < NimPlayer.getId(); i++) {
                String userName = NimPlayer.getPlayer()[i].getUserName().trim();
                if (removeUserName != null && userName.equals(removeUserName)) {
                    NimPlayer.getPlayer()[i] = null;
                    System.out.println("Remove successfully!");// A test to see if the code runs

                } else {
                    System.out.println("The player does not exist");   
                }
            } 
        }

        if (commandin.equals("editplayer")) {
            String inName = in.nextLine();

            String[] splittedLine = inName.split(",");
            if (splittedLine!=null && splittedLine.length==3) {
                String userName = splittedLine[0].trim();
                String familyName = splittedLine[1].trim();
                String givenName = splittedLine[2].trim();
                //System.out.println(userName+","+familyName+","+givenName);//Test if in name in the if loop
                for (int i = 0; i < NimPlayer.getId(); i++) {
                    String userCheck = NimPlayer.getPlayer()[i].getUserName().trim();
                    if (userName != null && userCheck.equals(userName)) {
                        NimPlayer.getPlayer()[i].setFamilyName(familyName);
                        NimPlayer.getPlayer()[i].setGivenName(givenName);

                        System.out.println("Edit successfully");

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("The player does not exist.");
                    }
                }            
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid in! Please enter again.");
            }      
        }

        if (commandin.equals("displayplayer")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < NimPlayer.getId(); i++) {
                String userName = NimPlayer.getPlayer()[i].getUserName();
                String familyName = NimPlayer.getPlayer()[i].getfamilyName();
                String givenName = NimPlayer.getPlayer()[i].getGivenName();

                System.out.println(userName+","+familyName+""+givenName);
            }
        }

        if (commandin.equals("startgame")) {
            String dataIn = in.nextLine();
            String [] data = splitData(dataIn);
            //Check if player in the array
            if (data.length==4 && data !=null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < NimPlayer.getId(); i++) {
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < NimPlayer.getId(); j++) {
                        String player1 = NimPlayer.getPlayer()[i].getUserName();
                        String player2 = NimPlayer.getPlayer()[j].getUserName();
                        if (player1==null || player2==null) {
                            System.out.println("One of the players does not exist. Please enter again");
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Data built successfully.Game starts!");
                            break;
                        }
                    } 
                }
                dataIn = in.nextLine();
            }
            int dataStone = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
            int dataRemoval = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);

    }
}}



//username, given name, family name, number of game played, number of games won
public class NimPlayer {
private String userName;
private String familyName;
private String givenName;

static NimPlayer[] playerList = new NimPlayer[10]; // set an array here
static int id;

//define NimPlayer data type
public NimPlayer(String userName,String surName, String givenName) {
    this.userName = userName;
    this.familyName = surName;
    this.givenName = givenName;
}
// create new data using NimPlayer data type
public static void createPlayer(String userName, String familyName, String givenName) {
    if (id<10) {
        playerList[id++] = new NimPlayer(userName, familyName, givenName);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Cannot add more players.");
    }
}
public static int getId() {
    return id;
}
public static NimPlayer [] getPlayer() {
    return playerList;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
public void setFamilyName(String familyName) {
    this.familyName = familyName;
}
public void setGivenName(String givenName) {
    this.givenName = givenName;
}    
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public String getfamilyName() {
    return familyName;
}
public String getGivenName() {
    return givenName;
}


}
```

Above are my Nimsys and NimPlayers class. So far, I have a question:

Is it wrong to manipulate the players in the Nimplayer? 
Or it is better to create an object in Nimsys if I want to store the record and the times game played?

```
public class NimGame {

int stoneBalance;
int stars;

public int initializeStone(int startStones) {
    stoneBalance = startStones;
    return stoneBalance;
}

public void removeStones(int stonesTaken) {
    int updatedBalance = stoneBalance - stonesTaken;
    stoneBalance = updatedBalance;
}

public void printStar(int star) {
    stars = star;
    stars = stoneBalance;
    for (int stars = 1; stars <= star; stars++) {
        System.out.print(" *");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String playOrNot;
do {
    System.out.println("Initial stone count: "+datastone);
    System.out.println("Maximum stone removal: "+dataRemoval);
    System.out.println("Player 1: "+player1.getUserName());
    System.out.println("Player 2: "+player2.getUserName());

    // while stoneBalance > 0, two players keep playing the game
    while (stoneBalance > 0) {
        System.out.print(initialStone + " stones left:");
        printStar(initialStone);
        // player1's turn and remove the stones; decision of winning

        System.out.println(player1 + "'s turn - remove how many?\n");
        int takeStone = in.nextInt();
        while (takeStone > dataRemoval || takeStone <= 0) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Invalid, you need to remove stones under upper "+ 
                    "bound limit or above 0. \n Please enter again.");
            takeStone = in.nextInt();
        }
        removeStones(takeStone); //remove the stone

        if (stoneBalance > 0) {
            //show the remaining stones
            System.out.print(stoneBalance + " stones left:"); 
            printStar(stoneBalance);
        } else if (stoneBalance <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Game Over\n" + player2 + " wins!\n");
            break;
        }

        // player2's turn and remove the stones; decision of winning

        System.out.println(player2 + "'s turn - remove how many?\n");
        takeStone = in.nextInt();
        while (takeStone > dataRemoval || takeStone <= 0) {
            System.out.println(
                    "Invalid, you need to remove stones under upper " + 
                    "bound limit or above 0. \n Please enter again.");
            takeStone = in.nextInt();
        }
        removeStones(takeStone);

        if (stoneBalance > 0) {
            System.out.print(stoneBalance + " stones left:");
            printStar(stoneBalance);
        } else if (stoneBalance <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Game Over\n" + player1 + " wins!\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    // ask players to play again
    in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Do you want to play again (Y/N):");
    playOrNot = in.nextLine();

} while (playOrNot.equals("Y"));
}
```

And this above is my NimGame class. It's the process of the classical Nim game. What should I do to introduce the player? What I did in Nimsys is only to check if players are inside the playerList.

Thanks for taking the time to review my code. Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a side note (because it won't affect the execution of the program), the name of an identifier should be self-explanatory e.g. your `getPlayer` method should be named as `getPlayerList` as it is returning the `playerList`, not a single player.

Your logic for `startgame` should be as follows:

```
if (commandin.equals("startgame")) {
    String dataIn = null, player1 = null, player2 = null;
    do {
        dataIn = in.nextLine();
        String [] data = splitData(dataIn);
        //Check if player in the array
        if (data !=null && data.length==4) {
            NimPlayer[] players = NimPlayer.getPlayerList();
            for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) { 
                if(players[i].getUserName().equals(data[2])) {// Checking player1         
                    player1 = players[i].getUserName();
                    break;
                } 
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) { 
                if(players[i].getUserName().equals(data[3])) {// Checking player2       
                    player2 = players[i].getUserName();
                    break;
                } 
            }
        } 
    } while(player1 == null || player2 == null)
    //...
}
```

You can put the repeated code in a function to make your program modular e.g.

```
String findPlayerByName(String name){
    String player = null;
    NimPlayer[] players = NimPlayer.getPlayerList();
    for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) { 
        if(players[i].getUserName().equals(name)) {        
            player = players[i].getUserName();
            break;
        } 
    }
    return player;
}
```

Then, the logic for `startgame` will reduce to:

```
if (commandin.equals("startgame")) {
    String dataIn = null, player1 = null, player2 = null;
    do {
        dataIn = in.nextLine();
        String [] data = splitData(dataIn);
        //Check if player in the array
        if (data !=null && data.length==4) {
            player1 = findPlayerByName(data[2]);
            player2 = findPlayerByName(data[3]);
        } 
    } while(player1 == null || player2 == null)
    //...
}
```

Another thing I would like you to understand is the problem with the following line:

```
if (data.length==4 && data !=null)
```

It should be

```
if (data !=null && data.length==4)
```

This way, if `data` is `null`, the condition, `data.length==4` will not be checked because `&&` operator allows to proceed further only if the condition on its left side evaluates to `true`.

The problem with your line is that if `data` is `null`, you will get the `NullPointerException` because you will be checking `.length` on a `null` reference.

> Now, I want two of the players to join the game, and do the following:
>
> - Score record
> - The times the player has played.

Currently, you have `userName`, `familyName`, and `givenName` attributes in `NimPlayer` class. You need to create two more attributes, `private int score` and `private int numbersOfGamesPlayed` with their `public` getters and setters. You need to use these attributes to store the value of score and the numbers of time a player has played the game.

Comment: It's really nice to see you again, sir. I understand your code clearly in checking two players' validity and thanks again for pointing out the problem. However, If I want to put the score and the numbers of games played for each player. Does that mean I have to rewrite the code for saving these two attributes? Or changing a way to build an object in Nimsys instead.

Comment: @Woden - you are most welcome. I've updated my answer to include a solution to these questions.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I am just a little confused about creating object in Nimsys versus manipulating data in just NimPlayer. Which one is better? Or there's pros and cons in each way? And for commencing a game (connected to NimGame), are there any hints for doing that?

Comment: Do not worry too much at this time. You are already on right track. The more you code, the better you will become and good ideas will start popping up in your mind. You should treat `Nimsys` as the engine and `NimPlayer`, `NimGame` etc. as the components of the engine. Each of these components should have the most relevant attributes e.g. `name`, `score`, `numbersOfGamesPlayed` etc. are the relevant attributes of a player and therefore these attributes must be part of `NimPlayer`. There is no problem with manipulating data of a player or game in `Nimsys`.

Comment: **Adding another comment as I could not complete my last comment in lack of space.** As I have already mentioned, do not worry too much at this point in time. As you will progress you will get better ideas. There is no harm in reworking at this phase. After a few projects, you will be able to think of good design before you begin working on the project. Wish you success!

Comment: Thank you, sir. It is really exciting that I figured out how to load into the game!!! I did what I've done on NimPlayer, defining the NimGame data type and wrap the NimGame into a function for Nimsys to use it. Have a nice day, sir.